# Visual Studio 2015 Git error message "Cannot pull/switch because there are uncommitted changes"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, git-pull, git-checkout, git-revert

I am having difficulty in doing a pull from `origin`. I keep getting:

> "Cannot pull because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before pulling again. See the Output window for details."

This also applies to switching branches. I get a similar sort of message, but this does not always happen.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and Visual Studio Team Services Git. On my machine I have a local `master` branch, and development branches. Every time I switch to `master` and then I do a pull I get the error message. I have resorted to doing a stash and drop stash (command line) and sometimes I use [TortoiseGit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit) to do the pull and it works.

What is strange is even if I try to revert (on the uncommitted files) using TortoiseGit it shows that it was reverted successfully (I have already tried Visual Studio undo, nothing happens). Trying to pull again, it is still the same problem. The uncommitted files will be there and sometimes when I do a `git status` it says there is nothing to commit.

Just a note: This can happen even after switching from a branch onto `master`. In this case there is no way there can be uncommitted changes, because I would not have been able to switch in the first place.

I am still new to Git, but I would like to know if there is a better way of solving this as I would like to use one environment instead of using switching between different environments for each task; it's easier for me to just do everything from Visual Studio. I have already read up on:

*[TFS/GIT in VS Cannot switch to master because there are uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885057/tfs-git-in-vs-cannot-switch-to-master-because-there-are-uncommitted-changes)*

**UPDATE**

It seems like this problem has to do with line endings.

By doing a `git diff -R` you can see that a line ending has been added, "^M", and it is different. Removing the `* text=auto` in gitattributes (then check for changes) and putting it back on again so that the gitattributes does not signal a change of itself that needs to be committed seems to help, there will not be any changes.

Comment: I restarted Visual studio couple times and then I was able to pull changes which took me to the merge conflicts screen.

Answer (score 66):

For me I didn't have any uncommitted changes or any untracked files, and Visual Studio 2015 still presented the warning.

1. Close the solution in Visual Studio, exit Visual Studio.
2. Open `Git Bash` (or your favorite Git UI)
3. Navigate to your repository (or open the repository with the Git UI)
4. `git pull` (or perform pull on the Git UI)
5. Merge happens (hopefully no conflicts, as in my case), `vi` opens (or the default merge resolution tool)
6. `:wq` then press `ENTER` in `vi` (or calm handle the merge tool which popped up optionally) and hopefully this resolves it just like for me.
7. Start Visual Studio 2015, open the project

---

I added a safer step-by-step by instructing closing and opening the solution and Visual Studio. This may be over cautious, and maybe a reload would be enough. This symptom could be a bug of the Visual Studio Git integration parts, and maybe it'll be resolved in the future.

Comment: I agree, always check if it works outside of VS, command line or any other Git GUI

Comment: Since May there were several VS updates and also updates to the VS Git integration. I haven't seen this mishaps for a good while now. Always update VS and it's plugins to the latest.

Comment: Sees this error all the time, I'm amazed that such a basic problem exist in such a major product...

Comment: I am on VS 2015 update 3. Got this issue while pulling from github repo. 
-opened the command prompt, -changed the directory to the git repo on local and -entered git pull

Answer (score 11):

Type `git status` into a command line opened at that directory. If there is red and/or green text, you have changed some stuff and not added and committed. Either revert the files (by doing `git checkout -- <file>`), or add and commit (by doing `git add --all` then `git commit -m "commit message"`). You can then check out branches or whatever else you want to do.

Comment: I have got untracked files.Could that be the issue

Comment: @kwiri yes, that means that you've created files since your last commit, and haven't committed them. Just do `git add --all` and `git commit -m "Add your commit message here"`. You should then be able to checkout other branches.

Comment: I will need to check up on how Visual studio is handling this because if you add files to a project they should also be automatically be added to commit. I do not have access to my source code at the moment but I am pretty sure I committed the files in the dev branch before switching to master where I tried to do a pull

Comment: @kwiri OK that's fine, if you could please comment with more information, such as the branch name where the error is occurring, what your `git log` shows, and what your last commit edited (in relation to the untracked files)

Comment: @kwiri Untracked files cannot be a problem IMHO. Problem can be if you have modified tracked files or staged files which are not committed. In my case I haven't had any uncommited or untracked or changed files, VS 2015 still presented this warning. Had to go to Git Bash and vi to unsort it. Sometimes VS 2015 crashes during merge conflicts.

Comment: @CsabaToth Good job Microsoft -.-

Comment: @RhysO Since May there were several VS updates and also updates to the VS Git integration. I have much less of these mishaps for a while now. ALways update VS and it's plugins to the latest.

Answer (score 9):

Try with these commands by going to the working directory of the project in the command prompt.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "your message"
git fetch origin master
git pull origin master
git push origin master //To push to the Git system
```

Comment: The issue is not about the commands more about the tooling in VS 2015 I would like to work in one environment with VS Team explorer.Because of time I would not like to switch to command and try to remember all the commands when we already have an inbuilt tool in VS , my thinking might be how our project is structured there might something we are doing wrong that is causing the issues

Comment: Worked For Me,  Thanks :)

git add -A
git commit -m "your message"
git pull

Comment: This worked perfectly to me! You can write these commands in the Package Manager Console in VS2015 and it works perfectly. My problem is solved! @Dhruv

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue in Visual Studio 2017 build 15.5 and what fixed it for me was going into Team Explorer *Settings* → *Global Settings* and setting "*Prune remote branches during fetch*" and "*Rebase local branch when pulling*" to **True**.

[image: Team Explorer Git Settings]

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2017/12/23/configure-visual-studio-2017-15-5-for-pull-rebase/

Also MS has the Instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-config?tabs=visual-studio&view=vsts#prune-remote-branches-during-fetch The facepalm moment is when you realize that "We recommend setting this option to True at the global level."  is not the default setting on those items.

Another instance of this issue occurs in the case where you have a separate build server and the solution gets frequent NuGet updates on the compilers. The First person to update NuGet Packages and sync the repo will have no issues, but if someone else attempts the update locally, before performing a sync, this message will pop up and VS won't allow you to pull or push code.  To prevent this issue everyone should get into the habit of syncing before doing any updates locally.  Once encountered, The best way we have found to resolve it is to stash any uncommitted code you need to keep (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vii.GitStashExtension), then reset your repository to the current head.

Comment: I donot have "Prune remote branches during fetch" and "Rebase local branch when pulling"

Comment: @Ziggler Really?  I added links to two sources above. Starting from VS Pro 2017 v15.5 through at least v15.8.7  these settings are listed.

Comment: The `Unset` _command_ is used in removing Git Configurations so it looks a little incongruous in context. With the latest Git Extensions Update the Git Settings page has a couple more options. @Ziggler: What's the version of VS you have?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Wasted a few hours with this issue

Answer (score 8):

This happens sometimes even with me. If you are using Visual Studio, there is an easy way to make your way clear.

For Visual Studio 2013 and above, follow the following instructions as this worked for me:

- Go to menu ***Tools*** → ***NuGet Package Manager*** → ***Package Manager Console***.
- Type **`git reset`** and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

That's it. Git will be reset and then you will be able to pull your request easily.

VS2015: Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package manager console. Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This issue usually occurs when there is file/change that hasn't been committed locally, but it is included in the pull action.

For example, you add a new file "test.txt" from your local Git repository folder directly (outside of Visual Studio). This file may be listed in the "Untracked Files" option, so when you commit changes, this file isn't been tracked and committed. And then another person also create a "test.txt" with the same path and commit&push it. Now, when you perform a pull action, "test.txt" file is included in the pull action and you will get the error message which indicates that there are uncommitted changes. So you need to check if you have files/changes that are not been committed and commit them before pull.

Comment: I am still having strange issues.I am trying to do a manual merge , Git says there are uncommitted changes, I do a stash, and it still says there are uncommitted changes. I do not want to commit my changes because I have not made any changes to these files and diff shows no changes on the files.I have tried reset --hard same thing it says there are uncommitted changes and the same files.

Comment: Thanks. when i have deleted the file in  "Untracked Files"  then I was able to switch my branches.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me. I just went to the project directory and checked if something is there

```
git status
```

Then I performed a pull by using

```
git pull
```

Then I restarted Visual Studio 2015 and pulled the branch that was causing this error. This time with no issue.
It seems like it was a bug in Visual Studio 2015.It only occurs when you undo your changes before pulling new changes. This same problem does not seem to be existing in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: This solved my problem of getting the error when applying a stash using VS 2019.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, too. An easy solution was that I selected *Commit* on the solution to see the uncommitted files (or easily use *Team Explorer* → *Changes*).

Then I undo each file using right-click. Before, I tested it by *Undo* on the whole solution, but it didn't work properly. Then again, I used *Team Explorer* → *Sync* → *Pull*, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

> Can not pull because there are uncommitted changes. Commit, stash, or undo your changes before retrying. See the Output window for details.

There is a simple solution for fixing this error:

First commit your changes stash or undo. Then pull the code. e.g.

git pull

Then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I've followed:

1. Refer to the path of the uncommitted file in the output window
2. Navigate to that path and delete that file from the folder
3. Undo your changes from Team Explorer in Visual Studio to add it again

Answer (score 0):

For me, the "Update" in the question was the answer. I added a .gitattributes file at the root of my repository and included only the following, so that line endings would only be normalized in cases where the file is text.

```
*.txt text
*.html text
*.css text
*.js text
# These files are text and should be normalized (Convert crlf => lf)
*.gitattributes text
.gitignore text
*.md texttesting
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was caused by having two files, "Web.Config" and "web.config". I guess this is ok in Linux/Unix but Windows can only store one of them locally. I detected this in azure devops exploring the files. I deleted one of them and problem was solved. I guess this problem could be caused by any file.

Answer (score 0):

In `Visual Studio` open `Output Window` and switch `Show output from` to `Source Control - git`, `git` will let you know about what stops it from pulling. One of the most common causes can be of course something like this:

```
The pull would overwrite your local changes to the following 44 files:
    <Here you can probably see a list of 44 files>
```

It simply means that 44 files have been added to the `remote` repository which are not part of the `local` repository. Open `Git Bash` and run this command:

```
git add *
```

This may solve the problem or end up to a an error like this:

```
$ git add *
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
TestResults
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

If you are sure about adding them to the `local` repro, just add them using `git add * -f` or remove mistakenly added files from `remote`.

Hope this helps.