# Switch to new branch in tfs/git without any changes, but tfs/git shows files have been changed?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, tfs

After working in one of my branches in Visual Studio 2013 and then switching to another branch and then trying to switch back to another branch tfs/git is saying that I have 10 files that have changed, files that if you open them up and compare with unmodified, there aren't any lines that would indicate a change has been made. Both files are identical but tfs/git thinks there is some sort of change?

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Tell me about your line endings.

Comment: @EdwardThomson - I have the default settings for line endings in VS. I'm seeing there are several plugins to help with this issue which I will try.

Comment: pick your last commit number and just do "git reset --hard <commit#>", that will reset your local source so you can just switch branches.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do your team member have the same issue?

Comment: Can you run git diff -R command to check the changes? Refer to the Update section in this question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647308/visual-studio-2015-git-cannot-pull-switch-because-there-are-uncommitted-changes

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT - If I run that command I see 'LF will be replaced by CRLF in file foo.js' - Thanks for pointing out a useful command! :)

Comment: So you can fix your issue now?