# Getting an error in Visual Studio 2015 "When pulling data from git"

Tags: git

I am facing the below error when I am pulling data from git using the git pull from **Bitbucket Repository** in VS 2015.

> Cannot pull because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo
>   your changes before pulling again. See the Output window for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2015 Git error message "Cannot pull/switch because there are uncommitted changes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647308/visual-studio-2015-git-error-message-cannot-pull-switch-because-there-are-uncom)

Answer (score 0):

Read this question and answers:

> [Visual Studio 2015 Git error message "Cannot pull/switch because there are uncommitted changes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647308/visual-studio-2015-git-error-message-cannot-pull-switch-because-there-are-uncom)

You have to use `stash` before pulling and `unstash` it after pulling use these commands: